# Using dplyr to convert variable from int to date

Tags: r

I have this data frame below called "Customer" :

```
     DOB person_age   Twentile
19660422         53        6
19620329         57        17
19500419         69        1
19630405         56        12
19670327         52        13
19540408         65        4
```

I want to convert the "DOB" variable to date using dplyr package so the date is in format of yymmdd.
I have tried this

```
Customer<-dplyr::mutate(Customer,Twentile=factor(Twentile)
                  ,DOB=as.Date(as.numeric(DOB)))


Customer<-dplyr::mutate(Customer,Twentile=factor(Twentile)
                  ,DOB=as.Date(as.character(DOB,format="%Y%M%D)))
```

But none of these is working,please can someone help please

Comment: You are specifying the incorrect date format. Use `format = "%Y%m%d"`. https://devhints.io/datetime

Answer (score 2):

`lubridate::ymd` is your friend:

```
> DOB<-c('19660422','19620329','19500419')
> 
> library(lubridate)
> 
> ymd(DOB)
[1] "1966-04-22" "1962-03-29" "1950-04-19"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
library(dplyr)
Customer <- Customer %>% 
  mutate(Twentile=factor(Twentile), 
         DOB = as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(DOB)), 
                          origin="1970-01-01", 
                          tz="GMT"))
```